# How to translate Organic Groups Menu?

Tags: routes, organic-groups, i18n-l10n

I can translate a normal menu easily, but how do I translate an [Organic Groups Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_menu)?

Answer (score 0):

Good question (+1) but be aware that this is a known issue about the [OG Menu](https://www.drupal.org/project/og_menu) module.

There are a few issues related to it, and [issue 2348821](https://www.drupal.org/node/2348821) contains a great summary of these (related) issues. It also includes some patches ([the patch in #9](https://www.drupal.org/node/2348821#comment-9943765) seems to be the recommended one to consider).

The issue is sill in status "needs review", so maybe you want to consider participating in that review? I.e. check if that patch works for you, and update the issue with your review results?